# Error with JPA query

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, casting

I am creating web service to get drop down list based on another drop down list.

**JPA class:**

```
public interface TbiAuthorizationMasterDao extends CrudRepository<TbiAuthorizationMaster, Integer>, JpaRepository<TbiAuthorizationMaster, Integer> {

@Query("select a.authorizationName from TbiAuthorizationMaster a, TbiAuthorizationDetail d where a.authorizationId=d.tbiAuthorizationMaster.authorizationId and d.valueName=?1")
    List<TbiAuthorizationMaster> findByValueName(String valueName);
}
```

**Persistence class:**

```
@Override
    public List getReportList(String reportType) {
        List<TbiAuthorizationMaster> reportList = tbiAuthorizationMasterDao.findByValueName(reportType);
        List<AuthMaster> detailResponse = new ArrayList<>();

        for(TbiAuthorizationMaster aDeatil: reportList){
            AuthMaster res = new AuthMaster();
            res.setAuthorizationId(aDeatil.getAuthorizationId());
            res.setAuthorizationName(aDeatil.getAuthorizationName());
            detailResponse.add(res);
        }
        return detailResponse;
    }
```

I am getting error which i am not understanding. Bcoz i have used same in other service. It was working fine, in this it is not working where i am joining 2 tables in query

**Error log :**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to com.acinfotech.timebound.jpa.model.TbiAuthorizationMaster
    at com.acinfotech.timebound.jpa.service.ReportJobsPersistenceServiceImpl.getReportList(ReportJobsPersistenceServiceImpl.java:7876)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.getReportList(Unknown Source)
    at com.acinfotech.timebound.restservice.service.RestServiceImpl.getReportList(RestServiceImpl.java:2771)
    at com.acinfotech.timebound.restservice.service.RestrsService.listReports(RestrsService.java:9940)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Error in the line:

```
for(TbiAuthorizationMaster aDeatil: reportList){
```

can someone please help in this.

Comment: This query return String List.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to cast `a.authorizationName` (I guess it's `String`) to `TbiAuthorizationMaster` class.

Try changing query to:

```
@Query("select a from TbiAuthorizationMaster a, TbiAuthorizationDetail d where a.authorizationId=d.tbiAuthorizationMaster.authorizationId and d.valueName=?1")
List<TbiAuthorizationMaster> findByValueName(String valueName);
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that you are selecting a `String` in your query and you are assigning result to a list of your `TbiAuthorizationMaster` objects.

So you are trying to cast a `String` to `TbiAuthorizationMaster` class.

You have two choices here:

**1.** Change your query like this so it will return the whole `TbiAuthorizationMaster` object:

```
@Query("select a from TbiAuthorizationMaster a, TbiAuthorizationDetail d where a.authorizationId=d.tbiAuthorizationMaster.authorizationId and d.valueName=?1")
List<TbiAuthorizationMaster> findByValueName(String valueName);
```

**2.** Or to use a `List<String>` in result to match the `authorizationName`, like this:

```
@Query("select a.authorizationName from TbiAuthorizationMaster a, TbiAuthorizationDetail d where a.authorizationId=d.tbiAuthorizationMaster.authorizationId and d.valueName=?1")
List<String> findByValueName(String valueName);
```

Comment: Yes, you can do it the two ways.

Comment: You have to change your for loop as well: `for(String aDeatil: reportList){`

Comment: ya i have changed, but inside loop i am getting authorization data from model class , right? that was the problem again. anyway it is working now. thanks a lot :)